# Powering a 6-Pin DAC-08B035 LCD Inverter

Tags: power, lcd, inverter, display, pinout

i have an old LCD Panel(N141X6 -L01) from a Fujitsu Siemens laptop and an inverter(DAC-08B035) for it. Before connecting the whole thing to a raspberry pi(and buying the necessary controller board), I want to test the inverter(and the backlight of the display). The inverter has a 6-Pin connector with

- white
- grey
- dark blue
- blue
- green
- yellow

cables. I tried to figure them out myself, but I didnt find any documentation for this board nor anything useful. The white and the grey ones are doubled and there is a fuse(transparent thing with a thin copper wire in it) attached to them. They also have the widest road on the PCB. The dark blue one is going backwards under the connector and coming out there. The blue one goes up and the green and the yellow ones seem to be doubled, too. [image: front] [image: back]
I will be happy to hear your thoughts! Thanks!

**EDIT:** Updated the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is a Fuse (labeled F1 on the back). And based on the connections, White + Grey are VCC (Likely 12V, but it's can vary, its not voltage specific). Green + Yellow are Gnd. Use a multimeter to confirm, as they will be in continuity with the ground pad around the screw hole.

That leaves Purple and Blue as either Enable or PWM. Which is which, and if they are active low or active high is questionable.

Based on the [OZ Micro OZ960S Intelligent CCFL Inverter Controller](http://dalincom.ru/datasheet/OZ960S.pdf), you can trace them out easily. Pin 3 is Enable (3.3V on/off signal) and Pin 14 is DIM (3V Analog/PWM?)

FYI: You could simply replace the inverter with one that is documented. A LCD inverter isn't anything special, just a high voltage transformer. Any CCFL inverter or even a neon inverter would work.

Answer (score 1):

This will require investigations from your side.

Start out with a multimeter, and test pins: Where do the traces end?

For example, from your somewhat noisy photo it seams the two leftmost pins of the connector end up on the same copper plane; verify that. Chances are it's a power or ground plane.

Then there's the three three/five-legged black packages right next to the connector. Probably low dropout linear regulators. If you can make out any markings on these black packages, you'll probably be able to figure out which range of voltages to expect at their inputs and outputs.

Other than that, good luck with finding a datasheet for the (possibly custom) IC in the middle; I don't know what it does, but judging from its position, I'd say it probably controls the function of the other ICs. I'm not sure you will get this thing to work without sending it some commands over one of the cables.

Comment: so it's a 5V output regulator. That doesn't say much about the input voltage on pin 1 (probably something between 5.5V - 10V), but it tells you that a) there's probably something logical powered and b) whatever connects to pin2 is ground.